# Trying to show message in asp.net using Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am doing project in asp.net in C#. I am trying to show message in script format. 
For that i am using the below code

```
Page page = new Page();
page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Key", "alert('Your Full Name Sucessfully Updated...');", true);
```

but it is not showing any error. or warning. even it is not showing the messege.
kindly suggest me and help me.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't show up your message is that you're only *registering* your script; you have to **call** it from the client side.

Furthermore, don't create a new `Page` instance as suggested by others.

You can modify your `<body />` tag to call `showMsg()` using the `OnLoad` property

```
<body onload="showMsg()">
```

Worths a try!

EDIT: And add your javascript code as follows:

```
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "showMsg", "alert('boo ya!');");
```

Comment: Thnx for ur reply. But I have already define a function in Onload and I have to define it inside the button click. After the Fullname Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the existing page within a page:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Key", "alert('Your Full Name Sucessfully Updated...');", true);
```

should do it.

Comment: Thanx for ur responce.
Yes, I have also try this one. But this one is also behaving the same no respond.

Comment: Then check if the js is in the page source. If not, consider where in the page lifecycle you are adding it. ( as per @slavo )

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of the page object and registering the script with this new instance. Instead, you should register it with the current page that is executing.

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Key", "alert('Your Full Name Sucessfully Updated...');", true);
```

Notice there is no `new` keyword.

Also, I think this should be done on the Init event of the lifecycle and not later.

Comment: Thnx for your reply.
I have tried this one, but it is also not working.

Comment: Are you getting any Javascript errors when the page runs? You can check in a tool like Firebug and also see if the script has been loaded at all.

Answer (score 0):

The `new Page()` looks wrong.  Seems to me you'll want `this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClie`... instead somewhere.

The first test is, when you get the page from the server, does it contain any javascript?  Then, get the script to work right if it doesn't.

Comment: Thanx friend. But i have already tried this method it is also not working.

Comment: Ok.  What isn't working about it?  Does the javascript not get into the html output received by the browser?  It most definitely needs to be `this.Page...` (or just `Page...`) rather than `new Page()`.